# Why are good comments on a negatively scored "bad" answer faded?

Tags: support, comments, design

Is this a "bug" or  a "feature" that good comments are faded *(opacity set to .7)* when posted on answers with score of like -3 or more? I understand why the answers are faded, but are good comments that are left on them suppose to be faded as well?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers) is a page that contains an example. (It is in the accepted answer)

Comment: That's how it should be.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: It's a feature. Yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design. Answers which have been substantially down-voted *can be useful*, because they often cause folks to say something like:

*Oh, wow, I was about to basically do just that. Glad I read this.*

Comments pointing out why they're inaccurate and worthy of a negative score are in fact helpful, but quite often you'll also find comments that are just rude or snarky directed at the person writing the answer. We don't want to highlight those while making an effort to highlight others, and quite honestly, *many* just want to see the most up-voted answers without the added distraction. If you really want to dig to see why people voted the way they did on a post, just expand the comments - even 'hazed out' they're easy enough to read.

Comments can be great tools, but they *are* second-class citizens on our software - designed specifically to be incorporated into the parent post and then removed. Bringing even more attention to them isn't ... what we want to do, even when they clearly spell out why something is just plain wrong. The votes *also* do this, and are designed to be a much better (and more obvious) indicator.